# Is there no overlap of ticker symbol even if old company was unlisted or bankrupt?

Tags: stock-analysis, stock-markets

I want to know if ticker symbols are always unique in all time period.
Or is it unique only in currently listed companies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unique only in currently listed companies.

The V symbol on the NYSE for example currently represents Visa. In the past it used to be for Vivendi Universal.